# Graph theory vertex weights

Tags: graph-theory

Are there any graph theory algorithms that can handle vertex weights? From what I am familiar with (BFS, Dijkstra's, Floyd's) these algorithms only consider edge weights. Similar questions have had responses describing transforming vertex weights into edge weights.

Comment: I think, it would be good, if you give a specific scenario. :)

Comment: @MukitChowdhury If a salesman sells his product in each city for a different amount (vertex weight), and using each road costs a certain amount of money, what is the max profit he can make

Comment: The weight of a node really depends on the context and the problem being solved.

Comment: Seems, a dynamic programming problem. Is that tree or graph? Do you have to visit all edges? Can you give me the problem link?

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra's Algorithm can easily be adapted to accommodate vertex weights. Instead of updating the distance using something like dist[u] = dist[u] + l(u,v) you set it to dist[u] = dist[u] + l(u,v) + cost[v] assuming that the vector cost tells you the cost of 'traversing' vertex v. You also have to initialize all your distances to this cost vector before starting the actual algorithm. Another approach would be to change the graph such that a vertex v with weight v is replaced by vertexes v1 and v2 which are connected using an edge of weight w.

Answer (score 0):

> If a salesman sells his product in each city for a different amount (vertex weight), and using each road costs a certain amount of money, what is the max profit he can make?

If:

- the salesman is based in one city;
- can sell all his product in any single city; and
- the road costs are fixed values (independent of volume of product)

Then:

- Build a graph of the roads connecting cities with the edges weights as cost of the roads (ignore the sales price).
- Run Dijkstra's algorithm (over the entire graph rather than on a single destination) to find the minimum cost to reach each city.
- The optimal place to sell is the city where `Volume_of_product * Sales_price[city] - Minimum_Travel_Cost[city]` is maximum over all cities.

However:

- The salesman may only be able to sell a fraction of his product in each city.
- The transport costs for moving the product may be:

  - fixed - i.e. just the cost on the edges
  - or may vary with distance, local taxes, volume of product or many other factors - i.e. the salesman may need to hire a varying number of lorries to move his product depending on volume being transported and these may need to pay road tolls and fuel).
- Sales may be spread out over time so warehousing costs may be a factor.

These factors and more will affect the method you will want to apply and without knowing the full specification of the problem it is difficult to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not common, but there are cases of it. For example, financial clearing/portfolio compression has graph theory approaches, and systematic risk approaches too, systematic risk defines these networks of financial agents by: the set of agents (the size of the set), the endowments (initial notional of each agent), and the liability matrix (the amount loaned between pairs of agents). This is represented as a directed weighted graph, where agents are the vertexes, the directed edges' weights are given by the liability matrix, and the vertexes have weights, which are equal to the endowments. Based on this, if you want to write code that implements such a graph, I'd recommend not combining the edge weights and the vertex weights, just using a 2D array/list for the edge weights and a 1D array/list for the vertexes is sufficient.

Alternatively, you could use a map, from vertexes to vertex weights, and edges with their weights, for example:

A->[8,(B,4),(E,2)]

B->[5,(C,3)]

...

i->[v<sub>i</sub>, (j,e<sub>ij</sub>), ...]